# F# Clearly defined mutable variable errors it is not a mutable variable

Tags: variables, f#, mutable

I have several mutable variables in my code. All of them works except one!
Variable `d` gets several errors like

```
learn.fsx(33,25): error FS0027: This value is not mutable. Consider using the mutable keyword, e.g. 'let mutable d = expression'
```

The problem is that when you look in my code then the variable has clearly been defined as a mutable variable.

I think it is a necessity since the only thing I can think of should cause the problem is that it is something after the variable definition that makes it immutable again.

```
let seq = [2;2;3;3;5;6]
let exp = [[];[]]
let mutable points = 0
let mutable e = 1
let mutable state = ""
let mutable d = 1
let rec guess (x:int) =
   match points with
   |100 -> "learned"
   |_ -> match seq.[x] with
         |d -> match (exp.[((List.length exp)-2)]) with
               |[] -> if state = "right" then
                        exp.[((List.length exp)-1)]@[d]
                      else
                        state <- "right"
                        exp@[[d]]
                      points <- points + 1
                      if d = 6 then
                         d <- 1
                      else
                         d <- d + 1
                      if x = 5 then
                        (guess 0)
                      else
                        (guess (x+1))
               |_ ->  if state = "right" then
                        exp.[((List.length exp)-1)]@[d]
                      else
                        state <- "right"
                        exp@[[d]]
                      if (List.length exp.[((List.length exp)-2)]) >= 2 then
                        d <- (exp.[((List.length exp)-2)]).[e]
                      else
                        if d = 6 then
                           d <- 1
                        else
                           d <- d + 1
                      e <- e + 1
                      if x = 5 then
                        (guess 0)
                      else
                        (guess (x+1))
         |_ -> points <- points - 1
               e <- 1
               state <- "wrong"
               if d = 6 then
                  d <- 1
               else
                  d <- d + 1
               if x = 5 then
                 (guess 0)
               else
                 (guess (x+1))
```

Comment: `d` is being shadowed in the `match` expression: `| d -> match (exp.[((List.length exp)-2)]) with`

Comment: sorry for being dumb. But what exactly does that mean or what do you mean by "shadowed" ?

Comment: you have created another value called `d` and when you attempt to mutate it, it is correctly saying `d` is not mutable, call it something other than `d` or use `1` directly.

Comment: Oh! I see your point! Many thanks!

Comment: feel free to make an answer and then ofcourse i will give you the credit

Comment: thing is though. d changes from each recursive call and it is that value i need to be matched. So i really cant just rename it or set it to 1.

Comment: Use should look at tail recursive functions: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/12/22/tail-recurse/ Especially the part about accumulators

Comment: Post another question regarding converting the function to be more idiomatic f#

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `d` in the match causes that version of `d` to be used instead of the `d` defined as a mutable value.

Change the name of the value to something else of use `1` directly.

for example: `| d -> match (exp.[((List.length exp)-2)])` can become `| 1 -> match (exp.[((List.length exp)-2)])`